# excel vba - Using autofilter - can't pass the filtered range to a sub, it keeps passing the entire sheet range

Tags: vba, excel

I can't seem to figure this one out. I have a function and a sub where I call the function to get the unique values (from column N (text values)) from the range I've already selected from the autofilter. Somehow, the range keeps being the entire sheet range and not the selected.

```
Function UniquesFromRange(rng As Range)
Dim d As Object, c As Range, tmp
Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each c In rng.Cells
   tmp = Trim(c.Value)
   If Len(tmp) > 0 Then
        If Not d.Exists(tmp) Then d.Add tmp, 1
   End If
Next c
UniquesFromRange = d.Keys
End Function




Sub mainSub()
For Each key In fCatId.Keys
    With wshcore
        llastrow = wshcore.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A1:N" & llastrow).AutoFilter
        .Range("A1:N" & llastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=fCatId(key)
        lwmin = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(5, Range("H:H"))
        lwmax = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(4, Range("H:H"))

        'This does not work,  I want to get the unique values from column N
        'that are already in the filtered range. So far this shows
        'all the values in the column not only the ones already filtered.

         varArray = UniquesFromRange(Range("N:N"))
         'I've also tried this:
        'varArray = UniquesFromRange(Range.Cells)


         'Debug.Print fCatId(key) & " - " & key & "   " & lwmin & "-" & lwmax  & fData(key) & " - " & Join(varArray, vbNewLine)



    End With
Next key
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
varArray = UniquesFromRange(Range("N:N"))
```

use

```
varArray = UniquesFromRange(Range("N1:N" & llastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
```

In response to the additional question asked in the comments, you could copy varArray to another sheet (assumed to already exist, and being referred to by the object wsOutput, and output to be written to column A) as follows

```
Dim r as Integer
For r = LBound(varArray) To UBound(varArray)
    wsOutput.Cells(r, 1).Value = varArray(r)
Next
```

Comment: thank you! It works! need to wait a few minutes since the site doesn't let me mark it as answer so quickly!  Can I ask you how I can instead printing the values writing them in a new sheet?.

Comment: @sys73r - I updated the answer as simply passing `Range("N:N")` would pass all the visible cells below your table as well, which will slow down the finding of unique values (as you will have thousands of empty cells to look at)

Comment: how can I copy the Debug.print values to another new sheet?

Comment: If you are trying to paste the non-duplicate values to another sheet, have you just tried something like `Range("N1:N" & llastrow).Copy Destination:=wsOutput.Range("A1")`  `wsOutput.Range("A1:A" & wsOutput.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes`.  Then you don't even need your own UniquesFromRange function.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a simple loop to write varArray.  You will probably have to modify that a bit if you also need to write key, fCatId(key), etc, to that sheet too.